# Rewrite shared example groups in rspec2

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

In rspec 1 I could do

```
describe "Something", :shared => true do
 include SomeModule # which has the :a_method method

 def a_method(options)
   super(options.merge(:option => @attr)
 end

 it "foofoofoo" do
 end
end

describe "Something else" do
  before(:each) do
    @attr = :s_else
  end

  it_should_behave_like "Something"

  it "barbarbar" do
    a_method(:name => "something else")
    Something.find("something else").name.should == "Something else"
  end
...
end
```

That is, I could use `:shared => true` to not only refactor examples but also share method definitions and attributes. I realize the example is contrived, but how would one write it in rspec >= 2 without touching the `SomeModule` module or the `Something` class?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `shared_examples_for`

```
shared_examples_for "something" do
  include SomeModule # which has the :a_method method

  def a_method(options)
    super(options.merge(:option => @attr))
  end

  it "foofoofoo" do
  end
end
```

And call with `it_behaves_like`:

```
it_behaves_like "something"
```

**EDIT**

Joao correctly points out that this fails to include SomeModule for the examples in the describe block. The include would have to take place outside the shared example group, e.g. at the top of the spec file

```
include SomeModule # which has the :a_method method

# ...

shared_examples_for "something" do
  def a_method(options)
    super(options.merge(:option => @attr))
  end

  it "foofoofoo" do
  end
end
```

David Chelimsky discusses some new features of shared examples in RSpec 2 which may be pertinent in [this blog post](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2010/11/07/specifying-mixins-with-shared-example-groups-in-rspec-2/).

Comment: Yes, but in the examples of the example group that declares `it_behaves_like`, I can't call `a_method`. In other words, can you add the "barbarbar" example to your answer?

Comment: See my edit. The blog post is good reading and might help in your situation. I found it hard to follow your intent -- perhaps if you "de-obfuscated" the examples they might be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the blog post. And you're totally right, there's no reason for this obfuscation, the full example I'm trying to convert is open-source and found at https://github.com/gma/nesta/blob/master/spec/models_spec.rb. The "something" is the "Page" example group. "Markdown pages" and "HAML pages" and two types of "something else".

Comment: Yes, I see your dilemma now. The specs rely on the "surprising" behavior that was taken out of RSpec 2. btw Nesta looks very interesting, I'll have to check it out!